# Meteor 1.3 + React: detect subscription failure?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications, meteor-react

I have a simple Meteor subscription, and I display a loading message while the data is being loaded. But I don't know how to display error message if subscription failed.

```
export const MyAwesomeComponent = createContainer(() => {
  let sub = Meteor.subscribe('some-data');
  if (!sub.ready()) return { message: 'Loading...'};
  if (sub.failed()) return { message: 'Failed.' }; // How to do this?
  return {
    data: Data.find().fetch()
  }
}, MyInternalRenderComponent);
```

Problem is, the subscription object doesn't have a `failed()` method, only a `ready()` query. How to pass the failure of a subscription as props in a `createContainer()` method?

I know the `Meteor.subscribe` method has an `onStop` callback for this case, but I don't know how to glue it toghether that to pass a property.

Comment: Subscriptions don't have a failed state, they just provide a data set for client database copy. I guess you want to only provide the data if a certain condition is met. If that's the case, check for the condition independently, for example by creating a method.

Comment: They must have a failed state. What if I mistype the publication name, and there is no such publication?

Comment: Then the `onStop` callback is called with an error object.

Comment: Also, if I provide a callback for the subscription, I can catch this error. But since the props depend on the return value of the createComponent function's callback, I can't change the props in the subscribe's callback.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researching I managed to get this working and I think it answers your question.

Bear in mind I'm using Meteor 1.6, but it should give you the info to get it working on your side.

On the publication/publish:

```
  try {
    // get the data and add it to the publication
    ...
    self.ready();
  } catch (exception) {
    logger.error(exception);
    // send the exception to the client through the publication
    this.error(new Meteor.Error('500', 'Error getting data from API', exception));
  }
```

On the UI Component:

```
const errorFromApi = new ReactiveVar();

export default withTracker(({ match }) => {
  const companyId = match.params._id;
  let subscription;

  if (!errorFromApi.get()) {
    subscription = Meteor.subscribe('company.view', companyId, {
      onStop: function (e) {
        errorFromApi.set(e);
      }
    });
  } else {
    subscription = {
      ready: () => {
        return false;
      }
    };
  }

  return {
    loading: !subscription.ready(),
    company: Companies.findOne(companyId),
    error: errorFromApi.get()
  };
})(CompanyView);
```

From here all you need to do is get the error prop and render the component as desired.

This is the structure of the `error` prop (received on the `onStop` callback from `subscribe`):

```
{
  error: String,
  reason: String,
  details: String
}
```

**[Edit]**

The reason there is a conditional around `Meteor.subscribe()` is to avoid an annoying infinite loop you'd get from the natural `withTracker()` updates, which would cause new subscriptions / new errors from the publication and so on.